# How to restore the original size of a micro SD card

Tags: sd-card

I wanted to clone a 256M SD card on a 8G SD card.
This is what I have done to achieve this:

1. I made a partition backup of the 256M SD card with AOMEI Backuper
2. I restored the 256M partition to the 8G SD card with AOMEI Backuper, but I was not able to resize the partition, and I thought I can do this later
3. The restore was done just fine, but form the 8G SD card I only can see a 256M partition.
4. I have used disk management tool from win7, diskpart, miniTool, SD Formater, but my 8G SD card can only use the 256M partition.

How can I have back the full 8G of my SD card ?

Thanks,
Radu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this card into an old Samsung smartphone i5700.

It told me that the card is damaged and I have to format it. So I did.

After that the original storage size of the SD card was restored.

Great, I've learned something today!

Regards to all of you,

Radu

Answer (score 1):

When you clone an storage device, what you get is exactly that, a clon from the first one. Now you have the same partition table than the 256MB sd, and the 8GB sd now thinks that you have only 256MB, not 8GB.

What you can do is use testdisk to restore the first sectors of the partition table.

Other solution is that you save the files, and make a full format of the sd, or make a clon from other 8GB sd in that.

Comment: i thought of that, but it can't be done, because the AOMEI backuper identify this card as a 256M card and can't copy a 8G image to a 256M card.

Comment: then you must try to use testdisk or another low level tool to give format to your disk.

Comment: if you use Windows, you can try with MiniTool Partition Wizard

Comment: I have used Mini-Tool, but it was useless.